# How does magical healing affect medicinal development?

Tags: magic, culture, technological-development

In a world with a magic system halfway between hard and soft, which doesn't require technology due to said magic. It has to be remembered that magic isn't uncommon, but powerful magic is. It costs hefty amounts to see a healer, so peasants wouldn't. How would this affect medicinal development?

Edit 1: People wouldn't bother to research medicine because of the healers. Therefore, medicinal advances would maybe be considered magical advances.
Edit 2: Building on the previous edit, **research would not happen, and if it did, it would be in very small amounts, and not large enough to be recognised or acknowledged.**

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the magical healers are a strong *political* force in the land?

Comment: No. Politics are left the Duke and the barons.

Comment: Please don't accept an answer after 2 hours, give other people a chance to answer. Accept an answer after a few days. This results in time for better answers.

Comment: Zulop zig, it is customary to wait about 24 hours before accepting an answer. It discourages people from posting an answer if you accepted one already, and people from all over the world might have a better answer than me! Waiting 24 hours gives everyone in any timezone a chance to answer.

Comment: Sorry about accepting so soon. I'm new to this.

Comment: Your second edit seems to have answered your question rendering it invalid.

Comment: without a breakdown of what magical healing can do this is impossible to answer, you also should include a societal breakdown to narrow the scope further.

Answer (score 4):

As a medical professional, I hate to say it, but I think the existence of **magical healing would crush the development of modern medicine**. At the least, it would delay it centuries. The existence of magic would be a huge slap in the face of the development of scientific theory. Florence Nightingale would have become a healer and campaigned against medical "quackery." There would be LOTS of pressure to move magical healing into the realm of the common man, but if the rich could obtain reliable healing and the poor don't have access, there would be little pressure for serious people to follow medicine (which would suffer the same treatment as midwives and herbalists). Medicine languished even when it was clearly superior to the alternatives. Effective healers would become rich, powerful, influential (think Rasputin) and would quash the competition. Justifiably, at the time.

Comment: Wouldnt this spur medical development? Aside from the rare high power mages the average medical mage will not be super powerful. This means that they need to be smart with their energy, especially when they are employed in armies. When free they are encouraged to find non-magical means to heal people and save their magic (and time! They'll employ nurses just like doctors to divide their workload!). If magic can be used to explore viable healing techniques then modern medicine would start earlier! Since they'll likely hold land and power soon they'll want others to do the chores of medicine.

Comment: I believe in a world where magic is real, magic would be studied by science just like physics or chemistry. Rather then delay the development of medicine, it would be integrated into it.

Comment: Hey, folks, I'd love to say the positive view is how history has worked out, but I really question it. Maybe if the healers collectively became an institution like the Catholic church, but I suspect it would still turn out like the church did, where they would suppress the alternative view in favor of their "self-evident" superiority. I can see lots of opportunities for drama & good writing in the inherent conflict. Even governments would shy from supporting medicine - after all, doctors WERE quacks for a long time.

Comment: Even doctors with scientific training don't necessarily pay attention to good scientific evidence when it slaps them in the face. See this story https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2015/01/12/375663920/the-doctor-who-championed-hand-washing-and-saved-women-s-lives

Answer (score 4):

**It will actually speed up medicine development**

So as suggested by [demigan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48354/demigan) understanding of medicine coupled with statistics is quite new. However "research"  into medicine was not. The problem was that since the scientific method was not practised there was little way to know what worked and what not, creating doctors who believed that something would work without any proofs. Also, as mentioned, it was hard to separate quacks from professionals.

Having magical healing presumably solves both (depending on the magic system). To heal somebody (magically or otherwise) you would need to see how ill somebody is and whether the magic you are performing is healing the body. So a magical healer should be able to very easily see what the healing effect of certain potions and concoctions are. Furthermore since any magical healer will be a professional (seen against us normal mortals) it automatically adds a certain professionalism to medicine development.

So basically make a medicine, feed it to an ill person and let a magical healer determine the effects. Even in our current technological society, medicine companies would kill for this abbility.

Comment: What we havent covered either is the rest of the world. Early in history both science and medicine were more trial-and-error that didnt spread quickly, and only things that happened to work would spread eventually. Even if magical medicine remains guarded elite society the moment the scientific method starts its rise then magical medicine will simply be enrolled into the scientific method and then give rise to modern medicine. If necessary it starts without magic backing it, then eventually like the church it has to bow to progress and join.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think it would change much.

Scientific approach to medicine is fairly new, while a lot of people had done something to improve our lives like Florence Nightingale using statistics to prove how valuable hygiene was on the battlefield it didnt become a fully regulated science-based practice until recently. And even today there's millions that still prefer magical thinking when it comes to their health. Magnetism, soothsayers, people who randomly do stuff to your aura (or so they say), psychics (why though?) Etc. On the other hand people also still have magical thinking for bad health conditions. With the lockdown for most countries people feel like they are losing control and they use magical thinking to develop conspiracy theories that lead nowhere or are banana's, just so they can feel a measure of control in their life. 5G causes Corona (how?), Corona was deliberately created (why? How do you keep every single virologist involved quiet?), 5G causes harm to growing children (this was said even before it became active, how do you find out? Where are these children? Who tested it/found out?).

Anyway: throughout history people had to rely on what the salesman told you, wether it was a snake oil salesman or an actual person who studied for years (and subsequently does some bloodletting with an uncleaned knife and attaches leeches to you). Its going to be hard to filter out the real magic from those who fake it, but that was true in the past as well. At some point the scientific method is going to take hold, at which point all medicine will become science-based including magic. The "worst" where medicine will lag behind is with difficult operations that can be solved with magic fairly easily. However, any large scale warfare will as always boost scientific discovery, if all your mages are exhausted you want medicine to relieve the need for magic and to step in when magic runs out. And with the scientific method you could perhaps use magic to create short-cuts in medical research. Imagine if someone uses magic to find out about hygiene? Or uses magic to identify compounds that repel infections giving you penicillin long before our history would get it?

Comment: Because healers are the only real force who can heal, they would have a reputation for it.

Comment: @ZulopZig Surely, people would notice that even those that don't find a healer because of the costs can still recover from accidents and injuries? I would imagine that if the one casting magic didn't know that the person was dying of diabetes after a pancreas shutdown would not be able to cure it. Meanwhile, a proper doctor working alongside could help them pinpoint their magic to the correct areas to heal leading to greater efficacy and efficiency.

Comment: A "proper doctor" would be shunned upon for attempting to imitate magic,  or aid somebody with it, which would be considered unnessaccary.

Comment: @ZulopZig Not all doctors are the same. The general practitioner is not going to be using CAT scans or other more advanced techniques to discover what is wrong with someone and prescribe medicine. Similarly a medical mage would like to know what spell he's going to need or what treatment he needs to give. Spending magic to find out means running out of magic sooner, treating a simple cut or rash with magic is a waste. So magic would heavily rely on sensible non-magical healing to reduce wasteful use. This in turn encourages people to learn increasingly advanced non-magical healing for support.

Comment: @Demigan Thank you for your response, but non-magical healing would be discouraged. It would be considered only a healers place to heal. Spells work differently in this world, being that they mental as opposed to verbal, therefore meaning attempting to tell a healer what to do would be nigh-on impossible. Yes, they could say "Do this, do that," but chances are healers would know what to do.

Comment: @zulopzig I'm not sure why that changes anything? You would still want to properly identify what it is they are trying to heal, after all a broken arm is going to be cured differently than a heavy case of diahrea (very deadly without medicine) or an infection of the lungs. Knowing this before you heal would be vital. And again: I am assuming that one medical mage cannot heal every ailment in a single day, and would benefit from having non-magical cures to save up his magical energy. Unless they can really heal without limits, there is a reason to employ non-magical medicine.

Answer (score 2):

In a world where magic is real, from the start it would be seen by people as something natural and just part of the universe. It would therefore be integrated into science, just like physics or chemistry.

DJ. Klomp has [a good answer on how that would look like](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/175425/21222). I'd take it one step further - not only would magic be integrated into medicine, it would be integrated into pharmaceuticals too. Healing potions can be an actual thing. This does not mean they displace penicillin, because each may have their own scope to start with (if magic is a thing, expect the existence of magic-resistant microbes).

But *enchanted* penicillin? Man, your world is much closer to panacea than our own real world.

Answer (score 0):

Rich people tend not to go to places where they are likely to catch diseases or injure themselves, so there are two possible situations: healers charge high rates and only very rarely get paid and pharmacists get a lot of money(unlikely unless healing is very dangerous/needs expensive component for the spell) or healing is dirt cheap and medicine only exists for settlers or in places where healers are rare (maybe not at all if healers have a "per month" rate)